# Copy and past from open workbook into specific cells based on time of day

Tags: excel, vba

What I need to do is on a button click open another workbook, run macros from it, then after that copy information from specific cells in the open workbook and paste those values into cells in the current workbook. Getting the other workbook to open and the macros to run is going fine, but the problem is I need the copied information to be pasted into specific cells based on what time it is. I've got the following code which I THINK should choose cells based on time, but it's not actually pasting anything. Please let me know what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong!'

```
Sub Update()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\Redacted\Desktop\Booking Window Avai -working copy.xlsm"
Dim currentWb As Workbook
Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim openWb As Workbook
Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(path)

Dim openWs As Worksheet
Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Mail Format")
Dim rng_data As Range

'Application.Run ("'R:\Command Center\Primary Tools\Booking Window Avail-Open Tracking - Updated 20170928.xlsm'!refreshpivot")


Application.Run ("'C:\Users\jredacted\Desktop\Booking Window Avai -working copy.xlsm'!refreshpivot")

Set rng_data = openWs.Range("B17")

If ("C2") = "" And Now() > ("09:00") And Now() < ("10:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C3") = "" And Now() > ("10:00") And Now() < ("11:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C4") = "" And Now() > ("11:00") And Now() < ("12:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C5") = "" And Now() > ("12:00") And Now() < ("13:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C6") = "" And Now() > ("13:00") And Now() < ("14:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C7") = "" And Now() > ("14:00") And Now() < ("15:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C8") = "" And Now() > ("15:00") And Now() < ("16:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("C9") = "" And Now() > ("16:00") And Now() < ("17:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("C9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]

End If


Set rng_data = openWs.Range("C17")

If ("D2") = "" And Now() > ("09:00") And Now() < ("10:00") Then
rng_data.Copy
[currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("D3") = "" And Now() > ("10:00") And Now() < ("11:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("D4") = "" And Now() > ("11:00") And Now() < ("12:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("D5") = "" And Now() > ("12:00") And Now() < ("13:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("D6") = "" And Now() > ("13:00") And Now() < ("14:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("D7") = "" And Now() > ("14:00") And Now() < ("15:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("D8") = "" And Now() > ("15:00") And Now() < ("16:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("D9") = "" And Now() > ("16:00") And Now() < ("17:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("D9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]

End If


Set rng_data = openWs.Range("E26")

If ("E2") = "" And Now() > ("09:00") And Now() < ("10:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("E3") = "" And Now() > ("10:00") And Now() < ("11:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("E4") = "" And Now() > ("11:00") And Now() < ("12:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("E5") = "" And Now() > ("12:00") And Now() < ("13:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("E6") = "" And Now() > ("13:00") And Now() < ("14:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("E7") = "" And Now() > ("14:00") And Now() < ("15:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("E8") = "" And Now() > ("15:00") And Now() < ("16:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("E9") = "" And Now() > ("16:00") And Now() < ("17:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("E9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]

End If


Set rng_data = openWs.Range("E29")

If ("F2") = "" And Now() > ("09:00") And Now() < ("10:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("F3") = "" And Now() > ("10:00") And Now() < ("11:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("F4") = "" And Now() > ("11:00") And Now() < ("12:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("F5") = "" And Now() > ("12:00") And Now() < ("13:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("F6") = "" And Now() > ("13:00") And Now() < ("14:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("F7") = "" And Now() > ("14:00") And Now() < ("15:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("F8") = "" And Now() > ("15:00") And Now() < ("16:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]
ElseIf ("F9") = "" And Now() > ("16:00") And Now() < ("17:00") Then
rng_data.Copy [currentWb.Sheets("sht").Range("F9").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues]

End If

Application.Run ("'C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Booking Window Avai -working copy.xlsm'!UpdateACTUALSTrackingNoPrompt")
Application.Run ("'C:\Users\redacted\Desktop\Booking Window Avai -working copy.xlsm'!Email")
 openWb.Close savechanges:=True
 End Sub
```

It's not throwing me any errors, it runs all the way through. It just doesn't actually paste any values.

Comment: If you're just doing values, then you can skip the copy/paste and set values equal to another. I.e. `Range([destination]).Value = Range([original data]).Value`.  Also step through your code with `F8`, are your `If` statements working properly?

Comment: That's the frustrating part is that when I step through it works just fine. Let me try just set the values equal to one another. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Still not working. I'm wondering if my time formatting is wrong in my if statements. I wasn't sure how else to get the code to paste values into a specific cell at specific times of day.